# PHP / Laravel - Validating filetype from incoming mail

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently try to validate incoming emails into my application and save the emails attachments to my database. However, I want to control **which** attachment types are allowed.

I use **[Mail-Mime-Parser](https://mail-mime-parser.org)** for PHP.

This is my code:

```
$attachments = collect($email->attachments())->map(function ($attachment) {
    return [
      'file' => $attachment-> getContentType()
    ];
})->validate(['file' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png,gif,pdf']);
```

Above returns `false`, even though the incoming attachment is indeed a `pdf file`. This is the methods I have tried:

`$attachment->getContentType()`, whih returns:

```
Collection {#521
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => array:1 [
      "file" => "application/pdf"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have also tried to return the actual content of the PDF file to `file`, but the validation still fails.

I have also tried to:

```
[...]->validate(['file' => 'mimetypes:application/pdf']);
```

But it still returns false.

What am I doing wrong? How can I successfully validate the attachments mime filetype on the fly?

**For reference:**
This is the actual header content of the attachment, when I `dd($email->attachments())`:

```
  -headers: array:5 [
    0 => array:2 [
      0 => "Content-Type"
      1 => "application/pdf; name="Eksamenscase___BIGfinal.pdf""
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      0 => "Content-Description"
      1 => "Eksamenscase___BIGfinal.pdf"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
      0 => "Content-Disposition"
      1 => """
        attachment; filename="Eksamenscase___BIGfinal.pdf";\r\n
        \tsize=522462; creation-date="Sun, 03 Mar 2019 14:47:23 GMT";\r\n
        \tmodification-date="Sun, 03 Mar 2019 14:47:23 GMT"
        """
    ]
    3 => array:2 [
      0 => "Content-ID"
      1 => "<BEC725B483FD8944A5837620C72EF376@EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>"
    ]
    4 => array:2 [
      0 => "Content-Transfer-Encoding"
      1 => "base64"
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: Which `validate` function are you calling?
Because there isn't one on Laravel Collection.

Comment: Ah sorry. I am using Spaties macros: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-collection-macros#validate

Comment: Do you think it may be possible that Underlying Laravel Validator is guessing some other similar mime type instead of `application/pdf` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up only checking the file extension for now.

```
if (in_array($this->getFileExtension($attachment), ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'bmp', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf'])) {
     //Save the document. Valid filetype.
}
```